# using MySQL to create JSON with C# and JSON.Net

Tags: c#, mysql, json, json.net

I am having quite a lot of trouble trying to find a tutorial that will tech me how to use MySqlReader (with MySQL) to insert or receive data through a class object. The construtor is shown as follow.

Where I have used http://json2csharp.com/ to create these class I know how to serialize/deserialize a class object into JSON. my problem really lies in getting the data from a lot of different table in and out of the database connector via MySqlDataReader into a class object.

I don't know if this matter but I am using .Net 2.0 with C# 3.0 (visual studio 2010). Thank you in advance for any comment or reply.

```
public class Boardingzone
{
    public string zone { get; set; }
    public string time { get; set; }
}

public class Serial
{
    public string rsn { get; set; }
    public List<Boardingzone> boardingzone { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Serial> serial { get; set; }
}
```

This is what i have tried so far

```
        string sql = "SELECT Route.RName, RouteSerial.RSN, Stop.StopName, TimeTable.BoardTime FROM TimeTable INNER JOIN Stop ON TimeTable.StopID = Stop.StopID INNER JOIN RouteSerial ON TimeTable.RSN = RouteSerial.RSN INNER JOIN Route ON RouteSerial.RID = Route.RID";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
        MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        ArrayList name = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList rsn = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList zone = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList time = new ArrayList();

        while (rdr.Read()){
            string val = "";
            val = rdr.GetValue(0).ToString();
            name.Add(val);
            val = rdr.GetValue(1).ToString();
            rsn.Add(val);
            val = rdr.GetValue(2).ToString();
            zone.Add(val);
            val = rdr.GetValue(3).ToString();
            time.Add(val);
        }
        rdr.Close();
    conn.Close();
```

Comment: i have tried to use arrays to store each of fields within a rows, but i still still couldn't find a way to store these data into the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are almost doing it right. without going into too much detail, you need to instantiate the classes you want to populate:

```
 var currentRoot = null;
 var rootObjects = new List<RootObject>();
 while (rdr.Read()){
        string name= rdr.GetValue(0).ToString();
        string serial = rdr.GetValue(1).ToString();
        string bz = rdr.GetValue(2).ToString(); <-- made this up
        if( currentRoot == null || currentRoot.name != name )
        {
            if( currentRoot != null ){
               rootObjects.Add(currentRoot);
            }
            currentRoot = new RootObject();
            currentRoot.name = name;
        }
        currentRoot.serials.Add(new Serial(){zone = bz});

        ... instantiate other classes
    }
    rdr.Close();

 foreach( var rootObj in rootObjects) doSomethingWithRootObj(rootObj);
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the purpose of populating the ArrayList is, you will have to somehow populate your Model from your arraylist either by mapping or manually.

For the simple case why can you not just populate your model here?

One good approach to this would be to keep your Model in a separate assembly, your DAL can then reference this assembly in order to populate the appropriate classes.

Better still would be if you could expose your model as interfaces then the DAL need only use those interfaces and can have its own implementation - not sure if this is possible with the serialization method you use.